# can unity3d work with socket.io?

Tags: .net, node.js, socket.io, unity-game-engine

i'm trying to connect to my **node.js** server using **socket.io** client.
the problem is that unity does not support it, as well a the current .Net version.

i tried some 3rd party solutions like [this](https://github.com/NetEase/UnitySocketIO) with no luck (a lot of bugs and crushes).
can anyone recommend on a way to work with socket.io client on `.Net 3.5`?

Comment: Hey sagivo, it's been a while since you posted this question. How did you solve it in the end? Would be great if you could share that. Thanks!

Comment: @Nikola i wrote my own library for that - https://github.com/sagivo/UnitySocketIO

Comment: yes, I found your plugin, but really to be honest, I wasn't able to get it working. I didn't find any relevant documentation on how to import and use it, and since I'm quite a beginner in Unity that throw me off. Do you have some documentation that I missed? Btw, I found https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/21721 to be easy to use, but ran into problems documented here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28471071/socketio-for-unity3d. Any additional help would be really welcome!

Comment: i wrote it few years ago so i can't promise it's still good.. can't add more than the readme there.

Answer (score 1):

I revised the library mentioned by @arturocandela, because it showed some problems in specific cases.
[UnitySocketIO-WebSocketSharp](https://github.com/kaistseo/UnitySocketIO-WebSocketSharp)

Answer (score 0):

try with https://github.com/NetEase/UnitySocketIO

With that library found in socket.io wiki you will be able to connect to a socket.io server but using javascript, not c#

Comment: tried that, it's buggy and crush all the time. specially when debugging unity

Answer (score 0):

I know it has been a while, but I just found [this free asset](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/21721) that may be interesting.

Comment: It's broken :-/. I really don't want to do it the C# way; it's so verbose.