# send JSON data to Unity from Node.js

Tags: node.js, unity-game-engine, socket.io

I asked this question on the [official forum](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/socketio-for-unity.297396/) but I guess I don't have enough rep there to be taken seriously :O

I'm using Unity3D free.

Has anyone used https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/21721 with success? This plugin actually came the closest to working (I also tried [this](https://github.com/kaistseo/UnitySocketIO-WebSocketSharp) and [this](https://github.com/NetEase/UnitySocketIO) but they don't work for me).

I contacted the author but haven't got a reply yet, so was wondering if someone had made this work?

*(edit: I would like to point out that I don't mind buying some other plugin if you have used it and found it easy/useful to communicate with your Node.js server via SocketIO - so please recommend)*

Concretely, here's my problem with it:
I cant find a way to send JSON data to Unity from Node.js as it keeps getting an error.

I tried numerous ways, and this is one of them:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('a user connected');
    var data ='{"email":"some@email.com","pass":"1234"}';
    var dataJson = JSON.stringify(data);

    console.dir(dataJson);
    socket.emit('newResults', dataJson);
    console.log('server emited newResults');

    socket.on('fromClient', function(data){
        console.log("got msg from client");
        console.dir(data);
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        console.log('user disconnected');
    });
});
```

In Unity3D I use the following function to intercept this:

```
public void HandleNewResults(SocketIOEvent e){
    Debug.Log(string.Format("[name: {0}, data: {1}]", e.name, e.data));
    Debug.Log (new JSONObject (e.data));
}
```

but it crashes (it catches the error signal) at this point with (when debugging is turned on) this message:

```
SocketComm:TestError(SocketIOEvent) (at Assets/_Scripts/SocketComm.cs:58)
SocketIO.SocketIOComponent:EmitEvent(SocketIOEvent) (at Assets/SocketIO/Scripts/SocketIO/SocketIOComponent.cs:400)
SocketIO.SocketIOComponent:EmitEvent(String) (at Assets/SocketIO/Scripts/SocketIO/SocketIOComponent.cs:392)
SocketIO.SocketIOComponent:OnError(Object, ErrorEventArgs) (at Assets/SocketIO/Scripts/SocketIO/SocketIOComponent.cs:382)
WebSocketSharp.Ext:Emit(EventHandler`1, Object, ErrorEventArgs) (at Assets/SocketIO/WebsocketSharp/Ext.cs:992)
WebSocketSharp.WebSocket:error(String) (at Assets/SocketIO/WebsocketSharp/WebSocket.cs:1011)
WebSocketSharp.WebSocket:Send(String) (at Assets/SocketIO/WebsocketSharp/WebSocket.cs:1912)
SocketIO.SocketIOComponent:EmitPacket(Packet) (at Assets/SocketIO/Scripts/SocketIO/SocketIOComponent.cs:309)
SocketIO.SocketIOComponent:EmitClose() (at Assets/SocketIO/Scripts/SocketIO/SocketIOComponent.cs:299)
SocketIO.SocketIOComponent:Close() (at Assets/SocketIO/Scripts/SocketIO/SocketIOComponent.cs:184)
SocketIO.SocketIOComponent:OnApplicationQuit() (at Assets/SocketIO/Scripts/SocketIO/SocketIOComponent.cs:164)
```

Can you please shed some light on how to aproach this problem?

Comment: Sorry to forgot to mention that - no I don't. I'll update the question to clearly state that.

Comment: Then .Net sockets won't work for you afaik. The package you mention seems to indicate as much.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm using Unity3D free.

But SocketIO needs Unity Pro. If you want to use native .NET sockets.

> Unity Pro is required in order to build using .NET sockets. You may
>   use a replacement package if you don't want to use native sockets.

You can use [Good ol' Sockets](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/13166).It's usable for sockets.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't mind buying it, was just wondering do you know what's the difference with some other available plugins (did a search on few of them) like this one (https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/10872). Will I be able to use "SocketIO for Unity" asset once I buy the Good ol' Sockets?

Comment: Best HTTP is really good solution. Especially pro version. But It is expensive. By the way Best HTTP uses Good ol' Sockets for socket usage.

Comment: Yes, exactly that - it's double the price of the Good ol' sockets. Have you used Best HTTP? I have a game server written in Node.js and would like to use Socket.io with it, so am basically searching for the best solution - I don't mind paying for the asset, I just want to make sure that what I need will be seamlessly working if I buy it. Do you maybe use Node.js + Socket.io? Btw, if this comment thread goes on - do you mind moving to chat?

Comment: Best Http has its own [documentation](https://docs.google.com/document/d/181l8SggPrVF1qRoPMEwobN_1Fn7NXOu-VtfjE6wvokg/edit), Good ol' Socket [documentation](http://cdn.lostpolygon.com/unity-assets/good-ol-sockets/files/Good%20Ol%27%20Sockets%20-%20User%20Manual.pdf)

Comment: I don't buy Best HTTP because its expensive.if you want to use only socket communication maybe it's good solution.

Comment: Hmm, I've gone through the Good ol socket docs and this popped out: " This is sometimes required when you want to build for a platform that is not supported by Good ol’ Sockets (Web Player or Windows Phone, for example)". Well, if this indeed means that I won't be able to use it to export my game to web player then unfortunately this asset won't help me :/.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70763/discussion-between-nikola-and-baris-cirika).

Answer (score 0):

I used such code:

```
socket.emit('event_name', {"email":"some@email.com","pass":"1234"});
```

I do not know if it right. The function in unity is:

```
public void TestBoop (SocketIOEvent e)
        {
                Debug.Log ("[SocketIO] Boop received: " + e.name + "--" + e.data);
                );
        }
```

And output is:

```
[SocketIO] Boop received: boop--{"email":"some@email.com","pass":"1234"}
```

Perhaps it does't right at all but the result at least comes to unity

Answer (score 0):

Make these changes:

```
    io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('a user connected');
    var data ='{"email":"some@email.com","pass":"1234"}';
    var dataJson = JSON.stringify(data);

    console.dir(dataJson);
    console.log('server emited newResults');

    socket.on('beep', function(){
        socket.emit('boop', {'boop': dataJson});
        console.log("got msg from client");
        console.dir(data);
    });
    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        console.log('user disconnected');
    });
});
```

this is will work.